# Extending Transactional Emails

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, module, transactional-mail

There is not much information out on the internet about extending transnational emails. I need to be able to conditionally send emails to different departments based on the category and/or SKU of the item - where is a good start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to look at `Mage_Sales` module, more specifically:

**Mage_Sales_Model_Order**

- sendNewOrderEmail (queueNewOrderEmail in CE 1.9.1)
- sendOrderUpdateEmail (queueOrderUpdateEmail in CE 1.9.1)

**Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Creditmemo**

- sendEmail
- sendUpdateEmail

**Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice**

- sendEmail
- sendUpdateEmail

**Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment**

- sendEmail
- sendUpdateEmail